# Send .txt File to Default Printer

Tags: java, pdf, printing

Im trying to print one .txt file that Its saved on my PC. I take the File and i Send it to the `defaultPrintService`.

I have installed on my PC "PDFCreator" as Default Printer, but when I Open the generated File, has no information (only white paper)

Its my Code

```
// check that the chose file Works - This works because I can see the information
    File file = null;
    file = new  File("c:/Tickets/ticket" + c.getId()
            + ".txt");
    FileInputStream fileSteam = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileSteam));
    String line="";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Changed

```
//      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileSteam));
//      String line="";
//      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//            System.out.println(line);
//        }
```

// Create the Print Document

```
    DocFlavor docFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    Doc document = new SimpleDoc(fileSteam, docFormat, null);

    PrintRequestAttributeSet attributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

    PrintService defaultPrintService = PrintServiceLookup
            .lookupDefaultPrintService(); 
if (defaultPrintService != null) {
            DocPrintJob printJob = defaultPrintService.createPrintJob();
            try {
                printJob.print(document, attributeSet);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("No existen impresoras instaladas");
}fileSteam.close();
```

¿Some one have Idea because Information dont appear on PDF? 
Thanks To all

Comment: What happens when you comment the part with the BufferedReader?

Comment: While sentence will not work, but this part of code its only made to see that the file its well load. I think that the problems it is on the second part, but i dont find it

Comment: I think you should comment out the `while` loop together with the declaration of the `BufferedReader` - it brings the file to the end, and you don't seem to be rewinding it after that.

Comment: I have commented it and continue the same problem :S